# How to put title and summary in the titlepage in the first slide using beamer?

Tags: beamer, titles

My code is:

```
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\section*{Summary}


\begin{itemize}

\item first item

\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: what do you mean? I am new to latex and beamer... and this forum...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `\section{}` should never be used inside of the frame environment.

No garantie that there will be enough room for everything you try to put on the title page:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{AnnArbor}

\author{names}
\title{text}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]
    \titlepage
    \tableofcontents

    {\usebeamerfont{frametitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{frametitle}Summary}

    \begin{itemize}
        \item first item
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\section{section 1}
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\section{section 2}
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]